# Main Report Preview in Visual Studio 2008 stopped working "One or more fields count not..."

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, crystal-reports

When I switch from Main Report to Main Report Preview in Visual Studio I get the following error:

> One or more fields could not be found in the result set. Use Verify Database to update report.

I run verify database and it says the database is up to date. Also when I run the application the reports work. It is just the Main Report Preview that has a problem.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue, and received this error message:

One or more fields could not be found in the result set. Use Verify Database to update the report. Error in File filename {9FEE6406-1613-409A-B9BD-C5FDA24E3DEE}.rpt:

The rowset column could not be found.

I was using a stored procedure to collect data for the report, and sure enough I was passing an invalid parameter for the SP. Double check the type and value of the parameters if you are using a SP to populate the report data.

Good luck!

Comment: Appreciate it. Forgot what happened with this problem.

Comment: @Nick, is this how you fixed it after all?

Comment: Don't remember. I may have used crystal reports instead of what ever is of what was in visual studio